# Simulating interaction of Smart Fluids with Solids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulation, electromagnetism, open-source

> Is it possible to simulate interaction of Smart Fluids with Solids? Is
>   there a software capable of doing so?

**What I Know:**
The two software that I know of are Autodesk Simulation Mechanical and Computational Fluid Dynamics. The brochures and information about these software do not mention Smart Fluids anywhere.

**What I need to Know:**
Alternative Open Source Software that can do the job specified. If they can't, then I would like to know a way to do so.

**What I need to Do:** Study effects of electric current on Smart Fluids flowing through solid cracks.

**PS:**
Is it possible to include Radiation and Radioactivity in the scenario also?

*Thanks to everyone who read this question. Please comment to point out my mistakes as I am relatively new to Stack Exchange and would like to know how to use it properly.*

Comment: I think the amount of time you invest in the question should be in the order of magnitude of the time you expect people to invest into the answer. Because with your question the answer would be "None that I know of out the box but you might be able to extend OpenFOAM or Comsol to simulate that". Possible additions to your question would be: what you already found out, which physical effects you wish to simulate

Comment: Sorry @bgschaid for my laziness. I am relatively new here, and unfamiliar with the environment and work ethics. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Depending on the character of the fluid, you might want to have a look at http://journals.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/index.php/ans/issue/view/1244

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at ADINA.

http://www.adina.com/index.shtml

They have functionality for both fluid-structure-interaction and electrodynamic fluids. This paper may give you more insights into the ADINA functionality and also provide some background on computational techniques for the class of problems you are interested in.

[ADINA Electromagnetics Theory](http://web.mit.edu/kjb/www/Principal_Publications/The_solution_of_Maxwells_equations_in_multiphysics.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that you are being very specific when you ask about a **smart fluid**, it's only a fluid with some special property (i.e. variable viscosity). Second, the physics you have mentionned (fluid-solid interaction aka FSI, solid mechanics and heat transfer) are all based on PDEs. So either you go with a multiphysics software (like [Comsol](http://www.comsol.com/)) or you can opt for an open source library (like [deal II](http://www.dealii.org/)) to solve your PDEs

**Multiphysics software:** you have wide choice of existing modules that you can couple easily in weak or strong fashion. However it comes at a price, specially when it's about parallel computing (where extra fees usually apply for the cluster computing license), and you'll always be limited to the existing implemented features.

**Open source library:** you have at hand a powerful tool for solving a wide range of PDE systems, you can easily extend it to suit your needs, no extra fuss when running a parallel computation, and most of all it's ***free***. The only drawback is that you don't usually have the lovely user-friendly interface. Also, some time should be invested to work with the first computations and know how to extend the library, which can be a *a bit* tough for someone unfamiliar with programming